# F-statistic Two stage least squares (2SLS) regression

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, f-statistic

In Wooldridge's advanced book, on page 105, the F-statistic for 2SLS regression is introduced. Let me illustrate the computation step by step with the following concrete example:

\begin{equation}
 \text{ln(wage)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 exper + \beta_2 exper^2 + \beta_3 educ + \beta_4 kidslt6+ \beta_5 kidsge6 + u
 \label{wage_eq2}
\end{equation}
The predictor 'educ' is thought to be endogenous. I use the following instruments for educ:

motheduc, fatheduc, and huseduc.

I want to test the joint significance of 'kidslt6' and 'kidsge6' as well.
I proceed as follows:

1)Regress educ on exper, $exper^2$,motheduc, fatheduc, and huseduc, kidslt6,kidsge6, and I get the fitted values $\widehat{educ}$

2)Regress ln(wage) on exper, $exper^2$,$\widehat{educ}$,kidslt6,kidsge6 and get the residual sum of squares,$\widehat{RSS}_u$, from this unrestricted model.

3)Regress ln(wage) on exper, $exper^2$,$\widehat{educ}$ and get the $\widehat{RSS}_r$ from this restricted model

4)Regress ln(wage) on exper, $exper^2$,motheduc, fatheduc, and huseduc, kidslt6,kidsge6 and you get $RSS_u$

5)$(n-k)$ is the degrees of freedom of the model at point 2. Further, $k_2$ is the difference in the length of the coefficients between the model at point 2 and point 3.

The F-statistic reads as

\begin{equation}
 F \equiv \frac{\widehat{RSS}_r -  \widehat{RSS}_u}{RSS_u}  \frac{ n-k }{ k_2  }
\end{equation}

Is that correct?